# Where to implement initialization code in react-native functional component

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, initialization

I am following the functional pattern as given by the expo project creation wizard, and I have a component like this:

```
Search.js

export default function Search() {
   const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState(buildContentViews(contents));

   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
            <View style={styles.statusLine}>
               <Text style={styles.statusLineText}>{(pageInfo.numResults || 0) + ' Treffer'}</Text>
            </View>
            {searchResults}
         </ScrollView>
      </View>
   );
}
```

Now I have some non-react-native implementation for backend REST-services, which shall regularly update the search results. Therefore I would need to do something like:

```
export default function Search() {
   const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState(buildContentViews(contents));

   client.events.on('searchResults', (results) => setSearchResults(results));

   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
            <View style={styles.statusLine}>
               <Text style={styles.statusLineText}>{(pageInfo.numResults || 0) + ' Treffer'}</Text>
            </View>
            {searchResults}
         </ScrollView>
      </View>
   );
}
```

However I quickly get the error that too many event listeners are established, which is probably because the above code gets run every time the component is (re-)rendered, or in other words, whenver the component is updated.

So how would I correctly register the event listener and/or deregister the event listener in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` hook is your friend here!

This is how I handle registering/deregistering to a `react-navigation` event moving between the screens (I don't know how your **client** code works, this is just an example)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const onFocus = () => {
      // here I do something when the screen gets focused
    }
    // this is how you handle the registration to the event
    const focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', onFocus)

    // and this is how to handle deregistration!
    return () => focusListener.remove()

  }, []) // empty array of dependencies
```

1. In the body of the `useEffect` hook, you define your actions;
2. the **return** function is used to clean-up effects, the perfect place to remove an event listener;
3. the **empty array of dependencies** assures you that this code will be executed just one time (after the first render) and no more! No more reallocation! The perfect way to define an event listener!

Comment: Thanks, works. Not the most intuitive thing, neither from function name nor docs, but well :)

Comment: Actually, it turned out it only does half of the job. While the code is executed one per component creation, component creation itself is triggered by updating the component. This leads to an endless-loop once I add something like `client.loadResults` to the `useEffect()` function.
How would I solve this?

Comment: @user826955 this is a very strange behaviour. Can you share some code about where do you use this screen and something about navigation system?

Comment: I think you can easily reproduce this by using `useState`, and updating state from within the event you've registered in `useEffect`. Updating the state triggers component update, and this in turn re-registers the event. This will be fine as long as `useEffect` does not contain code to update the state (-> endless loop). Meanwhile I've found https://itnext.io/add-state-and-lifecycle-methods-to-function-components-with-react-hooks-8e2bdc44d43d.

Comment: And while I must say this is probably the worst/unintuitive API I've ever worked with, it seems like I've missed out on the `, [])` in your example, which makes the code run only once per component creation (speaking of _unintuitive_ ...).

Comment: That's a great article...anyway i often use conditionals into `useEffect` to check if I really need that effect to be re-runned...remember, even if you add something into dependencies array, that code will be executed after the first render (like the empty array)!